# gnu make recreating directory structure in target

Tags: makefile

I'd like to use GNUmake to do image compression and some preparations for my websites.

I have a structure like

```
src
    www.site1.org
        images
            foo.jpg
            bar.png
        css
            style.scss
    www.site2.org
        images
            baz.svg
        css
            design.scss
```

I want be able to recreate this structure in `target` directory while using some other tools to optimize/compile the sources like e.g. `convert --strip src/www.site1.org/images/foo.jpg target/www.site1.org/images/foo.jpg`

I can find all my jpegs using something like `SRC:=$(shell find . -name '*.jpg')` and even create a variable holding all the targets with `TARGETS=$(SRC:src=target)`.

But now I don't find a way of writing a rule for which would (naively) look like:

```
$(TARGET): $(SRC)
    convert --strip $< $@
```

I've searched the internet for quiet some time now but didn't find anything appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

You could use:

```
SRC     := $(shell find src -name '*.jpg')
TARGETS = $(patsubst src/%,target/%,$(SRC))

all: $(TARGETS)

$(TARGETS): target/%: src/%
    convert --strip $< $@
```

which basically says: for each word in TARGETS, match it against the `target/%` pattern (and record the `%` sub-expression), consider that its single dependency is `src/%` and apply the recipe. This is a GNU make feature, documented in section *4.12 Static Pattern Rules* of the manual.

By the way, `$(SRC:src=target)` does not do what you think because the pattern matches only at the end of each word of $(SRC). So, `foo_src` would be substituted with `foo_target` but `src/foo` would be left unmodified. `patsubst` is a more powerful substitution function.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I will try it as soon as I can. Do you know where I can find infos on the double colon syntax? I think I've seen that somewhere else but can't manage to find something on that subject. (What is this called?)

Comment: You probably also need to create the target directory.  Use something like `mkdir -p $$(dirname $<)` before you call `convert`.

Comment: Added a reference to answer your question about GNU make Static Pattern Rules.